# Setting Content for Bound Kendo UI MVC TabStrip using Razor

Tags: razor, kendo-ui

Having trouble setting the tab content for a databound tabstrip. I found an example of how to to it using webforms syntax, but can't successfully convert this to razor:

Here is webforms syntax [from here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/bind-to-model-and-avoid-load-on-demand.aspx#1855676):

```
 .BindTo(Model,
(item, navigationData) =>
{
    item.Text = navigationData.Text;
    item.ImageUrl = navigationData.ImageUrl;

    item.Content = () =>
    {%>
                        Some random content I want to appear
                <% };
})
```

Here is how I am trying to do it in Razor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("OrderDetailsTabs")
    .BindTo(Model, (item, model) =>
    {
        item.Text = "Part: " + model.WOHdr.OrderDetailId; // tab text
        item.Content = () =>
            {
                (@<text>
                    Test @(model.WOHdr.Id)
                </text>);
            };
```

Which produces the error:

```
A local variable named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'item', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use .InlineTemplate...not .Content

```
tab.Template.InlineTemplate = 
        @<text> 
            @(Html.EditorFor(model => tabModel, "WorkOrder", tabModel))
        </text>;
```